# Pull down search mobile app requirement

Tags: android, android-layout

I just received a mobile app requirement storyboard where there is written pull down search on top of each screen with a dotted horizontal line at the top. Could anyone tell me what this means and help out?

Comment: You should ask this question to the person who gave you the storyboard

Comment: you can use sliding drawer and customize it so it can be from top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sliding drawer but if u want to use it from top to bottom. than you can use this library https://github.com/chemalarrea/DemoSlidingDrawer